# How to buffer stdout until stdin is closed?

Tags: c

I'm making myself familiar with C programming and want to write a program similar to [expand](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/expand-invocation.html). The command line tool first reads every input from `stdin`, processes it and writes the complete result to `stdout`. How can I achieve this in an elegant manner?

Currently my code looks something like this. This works perfectly when processing files, but obviously when `input` is `stdin` after each newline entered by the user he immediately gets the result for the line entered.

```
char buffer[1024];
while (fgets(&buffer[0], sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(char), input) != NULL)
{
    /* do something */
    printf("output");
}
```

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Comment: That's how command-line tools are expected to work. If you want all the output in one place, try redirecting the output to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write all of your output to a temporary file instead of `stdout`, then copy from this temporary file to `stdout` at the end of your program's execution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what makes you think `stdin` will ever close? :)

You can use `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` to determine if `stdin` is hooked up to user input. (If it is, the function returns non-zero.) If that's the case, you can alter your behaviour accordingly.